# Transfer VB.NET variable to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, iframe

***VB.HTML

@Code

```
Dim SS_ID = Request.QueryString("SS_ID")

Dim initial_QRY



Dim ctrRecord

If SS_ID <> "" then

    initial_QRY = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_rsSKUSetup WHERE SKUSetup_ItemID='" & SS_ID & "'"

    ctrRecord = db.Query(initial_QRY).Count

        If ctrRecord = 0 Then

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\ushuam00\Documents\My Web Sites\EmptySite5\_Files\skuSetupGenericData.xlsm")
       Else If ctrRecord > 0 Then



       Else
```

End Code

***JavaScript

```
function alertCounter(){
    alert('');
}
```

I want ctrRecord to be placed inside alter of JavaScript. Now I have the VBHTML on event "onload" calling alertCounter() All I have to see if I can capture ctrRecord  so I can display it under alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this simple solution

display the ctrRecord inside the body where your VB.net code rest

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @ctrRecord
    </body>
</html>
```

then call JS via iFrame using onload event

Javascript

```
  function alertCounter(){
   alert(searchFrame.document.body.innerText);
 }
```